# C getline memory leak different behaviours

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, getline

I have a question about the function `getline()`, that seems to behave differently in two scenarios about the memory usage, as reported by `valgrind`. I post the code of the two cases and explain the behaviors.
I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

### First case

`getline()` is called in a while loop, reading all the lines of a text file in a buffer. The buffer is then freed ONLY ONCE at the end of the loop: in this case `valgrind` gives no errors (no leaks occur).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* buffer = NULL;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    ssize_t nbytes;
    int counter = 0;
    char error = 0;

    FILE* input_fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while ((nbytes = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, input_fd)) != -1)
    {
        counter += 1;
    }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(input_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

### Second case

The same loop calls a function that, in turn, calls `getline()`, passing the same buffer. Again, the buffer is freed only once, at the end of the loop, but in this case `valgrind` reports a memory leak. Indeed, making the program run and looking at RSS, I can see it increases as the loop goes on. Please note that, adding a free inside the loop (freeing the buffer every cycle) the problem disappears. Here's the code.

```
int my_getline(FILE* lf_fd, char** lf_buffer)
{
    ssize_t lf_nbytes = 0;
    size_t lf_bufsiz = 0;
    lf_nbytes = getline(lf_buffer, &lf_bufsiz, lf_fd);
    if (lf_nbytes == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* lf_buffer = NULL;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    ssize_t nbytes;
    int counter = 0;
    int new_line_counter = 0;
    char error = 0;

    FILE* lf_fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while ((my_getline(lf_fd, &lf_buffer)) == 0)
    {
        // Added to allow measuring the RSS
        sleep(2);
   
        // If I uncomment this, no memory leak occurs
        //free(lf_buffer);
    }

    free(lf_buffer);
    fclose(lf_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Valgrind output

```
==9604== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9604== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9604== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9604== Command: ./my_getline_x86 /media/sf_Scambio/processes.log
==9604== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9604==     in use at exit: 1,194 bytes in 2 blocks
==9604==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 6 frees, 11,242 bytes allocated
==9604== 
==9604== 1,194 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9604==    at 0x483DFAF: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==9604==    by 0x48E371D: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:102)
==9604==    by 0x1092B3: my_getline (my_getline.c:14)
==9604==    by 0x10956A: main (my_getline.c:38)
==9604== 
==9604== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9604==    definitely lost: 1,194 bytes in 2 blocks
==9604==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9604==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9604==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9604==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9604== 
==9604== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==9604== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first program is fine.

The issue with the second one comes from the buffer length argument to `getline()`. Your `my_getline()` always sets it to 0, meaning `getline()` allocates a new buffer each time (At least, with the glibc implementation you're using; see below). Change it to

```c
int my_getline(FILE* lf_fd, char** lf_buffer, size_t* lf_bufsiz)
{
    ssize_t lf_nbytes = 0;
    lf_nbytes = getline(lf_buffer, lf_bufsiz, lf_fd);
    if (lf_nbytes == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

and pass a pointer to a `size_t` variable originally initialized to 0 when using it. The existing `bufsize` variable in `main()` looks like it would be appropriate to use:

```c
//...
while ((my_getline(lf_fd, &lf_buffer, &bufsize)) == 0)
// ...
```

---

While it was easy to work around, the memory leak you encountered appears to be a bug in the glibc implementation of `getline()`.

From the [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html):

> If `*lineptr` is a null pointer *or if the object pointed to by `*lineptr` is of insufficient size*, an object shall be allocated as if by `malloc()` *or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`, respectively,* such that the object is large enough to hold the characters to be written to it...

and the [glibc manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> Alternatively, before calling `getline()`, `*lineptr` can contain a pointer to a `malloc(3)`-allocated buffer `*n` bytes in size.  *If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, `getline()` resizes it with `realloc(3)`,* updating `*lineptr` and `*n` as necessary.

These suggest that, in the case you're running into, where you're passing a valid non-`NULL` pointer to memory and saying it's 0 length, the function should be using `realloc()` to resize it. However, the [glibc implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iogetdelim.c;h=9e5dcd2edb71c852131ed2ddb97f5d64cf5069d9;hb=HEAD) checks `*lineptr == NULL || *n == 0` and if true, overwrites `*lineptr` with a newly allocated buffer, causing the leak you saw. Compare the [NetBSD implementation](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/stdio/getdelim.c?rev=1.14&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN), which uses `realloc()` for all allocation (`realloc(NULL, x)` is equivalent to `malloc(x)`), and thus won't cause a leak with your original code. It's not ideal because it causes a `realloc()` on every use instead of just when the buffer isn't big enough to hold the current line (Unlike the fixed version above), but it works.

Comment: I think the memory leak OP is seeing is a bug in glibc, btw. The POSIX documentation and glibc manpage for `getline()` both seem to suggest that if `*lineptr` is not null and `*n` is 0, it should use `realloc()` to grow the buffer, instead of `malloc()` to give it a new value. But the glibc implementation uses `*lineptr == NULL || *n == 0` to decide to use `malloc()`.

Comment: Not sure it is a bug. How would you interpret a pointer `*lineptr` value if `*n` is `0`? Is it valid or not?

Comment: @EugeneSh. From POSIX: *The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function.* And `malloc(0)` can in theory return a pointer instead of `NULL` (That can't be safely dereferenced, but can still be passed to `free()` or `realloc()`).

Comment: Yeah, in fact I am tending to agree after reading the [glibc doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html): *If you set `*lineptr` to a null pointer, **and** `*n` to zero, before the call, then `getline` allocates the initial buffer for you by calling `malloc`.*

Comment: The NetBSD implementation only uses `realloc()`, no `malloc()` at all. That seems like the better approach. OP wouldn't see a leak with that.

Comment: I think this observation should be made a part of the answer, at least as a sidenote.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Done.

Comment: Shawn, thank you so much for your help, I tried your suggestion and it fixed the problem. I accepted your answer.